# Python TurtleGraphics - Smoothing out random walks?

Tags: python

I need some help with this question relating to TurtleGraphics in Python:

A small detail of tipsy_turtle() is that when the turtle turns 90 degrees it immediately "jumps" to the new direction. This makes its movement seem jagged. It might look better if the turtle moved smoothly when turning. So, for this question, write a function called smooth_tipsy_turtle() that is the same as tipsy_turtle(), except instead of using the turtle.right(d) function, write a brand new function called smooth_right(d) that works as follows:

```
 - If d is negative then
      - repeat the following -d times:
            - turn left 1 using the ordinary turtle.left command

  - Otherwise, repeat the following d times:
          - turn right 1 using the ordinary turtle.right command
```

Here is my original function to get the random turtle movement:

```
def tipsy_turtle(num_steps):
    turtle.reset()
    for step in range(num_steps):
       rand_num = random.randint(-1, 1)
       turtle.right(rand_num * 90)
       turtle.forward(5 * random.randint(1, 3))
```

So, how would I go about making this work? I tried adding:

```
   if rand_num*90 < 0:
       for step in range(rand_num*90):
           turtle.left(rand_num*90)
   else:
       turtle.right(rand_num*90)
```

But it didn't really work out and I don't know what I did wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not completely clear to me what you want.  Do you want the turtle to turn some random number of degrees (up to 90) before moving forward, or do you just want the turtle to "visibly rotate" while changing direction, but still turn in 90-degree increments before moving?  Also, what version of Python are you using?  The turtle module got a significant upgrade for 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this sample clears up what went wrong in your example -- you performed either `rand_num*90*rand_num*90` left turns, or `rand_num*90` right turns!

```
if rand_num < 0: # don't need to multiply by 90 here - it's either +ve or -ve.
    for step in xrange(90): # xrange is preferred over range in situations like this
         turtle.left(rand_num) # net result is 90 left turns in rand_num direction
else:
    for step in xrange(90):
         turtle.right(rand_num)
```

Or you could write this as:

```
for step in xrange(90):
    if rand_num < 0:
        turtle.left(rand_num)
    else:
        turtle.right(rand_num)
```

For code like this, it's really a matter of preference.

Comment: Actually, if rand_num can be positive or negative, you only ever have to turn right.  (Or only turn left.)  turtle.right(-1) behaves the same as turtle.left(1).  At least in the turtle module I'm using (Python 2.6.1 on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do without the conditional for left-vs-right.  I don't have python syntax down, so here's pseudocode

```
turtle left randomly generated value 0 to 90
turtle right randomly generated value 0 to 90
turtle forward some amount
```

I.e., generate a random angle and turn left that much, then generate another random angle and turn right by that much.  This way you don't have to worry about generating or dealing with negative randoms.  You can keep all the random angles positive, and the combination of a left followed by a right effectively does a subtraction for you which gives a nice gaussian distribution to the changes in direction.

Comment: It's no harder to deal with negative random numbers than with having to choose left or right.  As I noted in my comment to Mark Rushakoff's answer, turning right by a negative amount is equivalent to turning left by a positive amount.  Python's random number facilities make it actually simpler to just always pick one direction and allow negative angles.

Comment: yeah, i know .. i just wanted to get it out there that there are alternatives to choose from =)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll venture an answer even though I am not completely sure what you want (see my comment to the question, and don't be surprised if I edit this answer as appropriate!).

Assuming you want the turtle to turn some number of degrees at each step, not necessarily 90, but not more than 90, then simply use `rand_num = random.randint(-90, 90)` and then `turtle.right(rand_num)`.